# Access NSCollectionViewItem outlets in the class with the NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

**Edit: This was fixed by casting the cell to a DCartCollectionCell.**

```
let image = array[indexPath.item]
        if let item = self.collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "DCartCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? DCartCollectionCell {
            item.imgView.image = photo
            return item
        }
```

I have a custom NSCollectionViewItem named DCartCollectionCell. In here I have an image view named imgView.

[image: CartCollectionCell.xib]

Then to load this cell in the NSCollectionView in the CartViewController class, I am doing this:

```
let item = NSNib(nibNamed: "DCartCollectionCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(item, forItemWithIdentifier: "DCartCollectionCell")
```

The collection view is showing the custom cell with the image view, stepper, button etc, but I cannot access any outlets in the custom cell class in the method where the cell is setup:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView,
                        itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "DCartCollectionCell", for:indexPath)
        item.imgView... (not available)
        return item
    }
```

I would like to do something like this to put photos from an array into the cell's image view:

`item.imgView.image = cartArray[indexPath.item]`

I can use this to put the photo in the image view, but I cannot use imageView inside the cell class to manipulate the photo (I am cropping it using the dropdown):

`item.imageView!.image = cartArray[indexPath.item]`

How can I put the photos from the array into imgView?

My CollectionViewItem has DCartCollectionCell as it's class.
[image: DCartCollectionCell class]

Comment: "Then to load this cell in the NSCollectionView in the CartViewController class, I am doing this"  Under what class are you hosing the collection view?

Comment: My CartViewController class contains the collection view. In the viewDidLoad for that class, I am loading the collection view with that custom item class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by casting the cell to a DCartCollectionCell.

```
let image = array[indexPath.item]
        if let item = self.collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "DCartCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? DCartCollectionCell {
            item.imgView.image = photo
            return item
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ itemForRepresentedObjectAtcollectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
    let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "DCartCollectionCell", for: indexPath)
    guard let collectionViewItem = item as? CollectionViewItem else { return item }

    collectionViewItem.imgView.image = ...
    return item
}
```

1. Drag and drop `Collection View Item` from the `Object Library` onto the middle pane.
2. Select the collection view item.  Under the identity inspector of the right pane, set the class to DCartCollectionCell.
3. Then access the collection view delegate as shown above in your view controller.

Comment: I am getting an error for CollectionViewItem in the second line of your answer. 'Use of undeclared type 'CollectionViewItem'. The class of the collection view item in DCartCollectionCell is set to DCartCollectionCell. See updated answer.

Comment: Have you set the collection view delegates to the view controller?

Comment: Yes, I have set the delegates. collectionView.delegate = self,
        collectionView.dataSource = self. The view is loading the collection view with the custom cell and I can set the imageView of it. But not imgView or any other outlets I have set in the DCartCollectionCell class.

Comment: No.  Do yo have class CartViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
}

Comment: Do you still have that error?  If you don't, you need to re-wire IBOutlets.

Comment: I have CartViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource { }. The CartViewController only has an outlet for collectionView, while DCartCollectionCell has imgView as an outlet from the image view in the cell to the DCartCollectionCell item object (under objects in the first screenshot).

Comment: I have fixed the issue.